# Convert pairwise distance matrix to column format in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a pairwise distance matrix (4x4). How can I convert from this matrix to column format whereby I have 2 rows? Why two rows? Because I don't want all the pairwise comparisons, just half of them as I show in the output. For example, if I had a 10x10 matrix, I would have 100 comparisons, but I only 5 of those 100 are relevant to me and those 5 would be species1 vs species2, species3 vs species4, species5 vs species6, species7 vs species8, species9 vs species10.

Input:

```
        species1    species2    species3    species4
species1    0   0.093165625 0.228683707 0.194066949
species2    0.093165625 0   0.155611221 0.129896673
species3    0.228683707 0.155611221 0   0.04360685
species4    0.194066949 0.129896673 0.04360685  0
```

Output:

```
species1    species2    0.093165625
species3    species4    0.04360685
```

Comment: Why only two rows?

Comment: Because I don't want all the pairwise comparisons, just half of them as I show in the output. For example, if I had a 10x10 matrix, I would have 100 comparisons, but I only 5 of those 100 are relevant to me and those 5 would be 1 vs 2, 3 vs 4, 5 vs 6, 7 vs 8, 9 vs 10.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you expect your transformed matrix to have only two rows but in general you could use `stack`

```
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text =
    "       species1    species2    species3    species4
species1    0   0.093165625 0.228683707 0.194066949
species2    0.093165625 0   0.155611221 0.129896673
species3    0.228683707 0.155611221 0   0.04360685
species4    0.194066949 0.129896673 0.04360685  0", header = T))

stack(mat)[, c(1, 2, 4)]
#DataFrame with 16 rows and 3 columns
#            row      col          NA
#    <character>    <Rle>   <numeric>
#1      species1 species1           0
#2      species2 species1 0.093165625
#3      species3 species1 0.228683707
#4      species4 species1 0.194066949
#5      species1 species2 0.093165625
#...         ...      ...         ...
#12     species4 species3  0.04360685
#13     species1 species4 0.194066949
#14     species2 species4 0.129896673
#15     species3 species4  0.04360685
#16     species4 species4           0
```

Comment: Please note the OP's comment that not every pairwise comparison is wanted. Not even all the adjacent ones.

Comment: @farnsy ah thanks for the comment. OP should’ve included this as a critical detail/explanation right from the start. Anyway. Your answer provides an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty unique request.  You want every other entry from the one-off diagonal.  OK.

My favorite way to take data from wide to long format is using `melt()` from the `reshape2` package. Then construct the sequence that pulls the values you want.

```
> mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text =
+     "       species1    species2    species3    species4
+ species1    0   0.093165625 0.228683707 0.194066949
+ species2    0.093165625 0   0.155611221 0.129896673
+ species3    0.228683707 0.155611221 0   0.04360685
+ species4    0.194066949 0.129896673 0.04360685  0", header = T))
> library(reshape2)
> N <- nrow(mat)
> melt(mat)[seq(from=N+1,to=N^2,by=2*(N+1)),]
       Var1     Var2      value
5  species1 species2 0.09316563
15 species3 species4 0.04360685
```